# How I get with a attribute value from a xml the other attribute values from the same node?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

hi guys i try to filter a xml file with a attribute value that I have and get all other attribute values of this node.

here is my c# code:

```
string search_string = "GlobalZoneEU";

            XElement xelement = XElement.Load(path_of_hw);
            var node = from nm in xelement.Elements("LICENSE_PATH")
                       where (string)nm.Element("FEATURE").Attribute("NAME") == search_string
                       select nm;

            Console.WriteLine("Show");

            foreach (XElement xle in node)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(xle.Attribute("NAME").Value);
                Console.WriteLine(xle.Attribute("VERSION").Value);
                Console.WriteLine(xle.Attribute("VENDOR").Value);
                Console.WriteLine(xle.Attribute("START").Value);
                Console.WriteLine(xle.Attribute("END").Value);
                Console.WriteLine(xle.Attribute("USED_LICENSES").Value);
                Console.WriteLine(xle.Attribute("TOTAL_LICENSES").Value);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
```

here is a snip of my test xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LM-X STAT_VERSION="3.32">
<LICENSE_PATH TYPE="NETWORK" HOST="6200@lwserv005" SERVER_VERSION="4.4.4" UPTIME="53 day(s) 21 hour(s) 10 min(s) 50 sec(s)">
<FEATURE NAME="GlobalZoneEU" VERSION="12.0" VENDOR="ALTAIR" START="2013-03-26" END="2014-03-31" USED_LICENSES="111720" TOTAL_LICENSES="147000" SHARE="CUSTOM ,VIRTUAL">
<USER NAME="SYSTEM" HOST="LWSERV171" IP="172.16.11.115" USED_LICENSES="2000" LOGIN_TIME="2013-04-17 12:42" CHECKOUT_TIME="2013-04-17 12:42" SHARE_CUSTOM="hweuser:172.16.11.115"/>
>
<USER NAME="admin" HOST="SERV171" IP="172.166.11.115" USED_LICENSES="720" LOGIN_TIME="2013-04-17 12:44" CHECKOUT_TIME="2013-04-17 12:44" SHARE_CUSTOM="pbsadmin:LWSERV171:1592_40960072_1356792762_826820"/>
>
<USER NAME="Be.M" HOST="4327" IP="172.168.225.105" USED_LICENSES="21000" LOGIN_TIME="2013-05-21 07:52" CHECKOUT_TIME="2013-05-21 07:52" SHARE_CUSTOM="Be.M:4327"/>
>
<USER NAME="Bell.M" HOST="DBG4327" IP="172.16.225.105" USED_LICENSES="6000" LOGIN_TIME="2013-05-21 07:54" CHECKOUT_TIME="2013-05-21 07:54" SHARE_CUSTOM="Bell.M:DBG4327"/>
>
<USER NAME="xu.d" HOST="DBG4970" IP="172.16.225.126" USED_LICENSES="21000" LOGIN_TIME="2013-05-21 08:15" CHECKOUT_TIME="2013-05-21 08:15" SHARE_CUSTOM="xu.d:DBG4970"/>
>
<USER NAME="xu.d" HOST="DBG4970" IP="172.16.225.126" USED_LICENSES="21000" LOGIN_TIME="2013-05-21 08:18" CHECKOUT_TIME="2013-05-21 08:18" SHARE_CUSTOM="xu.d:DBG4970"/>
>
<USER NAME="Bell.M" HOST="DBG4327" IP="172.16.225.105" USED_LICENSES="21000" LOGIN_TIME="2013-05-21 08:23" CHECKOUT_TIME="2013-05-21 08:23" SHARE_CUSTOM="Bell.M:DBG4327"/>
>
<USER NAME="xu.d" HOST="SIM02" IP="172.16.32.12" USED_LICENSES="21000" LOGIN_TIME="2013-05-21 08:36" CHECKOUT_TIME="2013-05-21 08:36" SHARE_CUSTOM="xu.d:SIM02"/>
>
<USER NAME="xu.d" HOST="SIM02" IP="172.16.32.12" USED_LICENSES="6000" LOGIN_TIME="2013-05-21 08:37" CHECKOUT_TIME="2013-05-21 08:37" SHARE_CUSTOM="xu.d:SIM02"/>
>
<USER NAME="hassan.a" HOST="DBG5199" IP="172.16.225.114" USED_LICENSES="21000" LOGIN_TIME="2013-05-21 09:24" CHECKOUT_TIME="2013-05-21 09:24" SHARE_CUSTOM="hassan.a:DBG5199"/>
>
<USER NAME="xu.d" HOST="SIM02" IP="172.16.32.12" USED_LICENSES="21000" LOGIN_TIME="2013-05-21 09:33" CHECKOUT_TIME="2013-05-21 09:33" SHARE_CUSTOM="xu.d:SIM02"/>
>
<USER NAME="xu.d" HOST="SIM02" IP="172.16.32.12" USED_LICENSES="6000" LOGIN_TIME="2013-05-21 09:33" CHECKOUT_TIME="2013-05-21 09:33" SHARE_CUSTOM="xu.d:SIM02"/>
>
<USER NAME="xu.d" HOST="SIM02" IP="172.16.32.12" USED_LICENSES="2000" LOGIN_TIME="2013-05-21 09:39" CHECKOUT_TIME="2013-05-21 09:39" SHARE_CUSTOM="xu.d:SIM02"/>
>
<USER NAME="zeiser-rasumak.a" HOST="DBG5200" IP="172.16.225.127" USED_LICENSES="21000" LOGIN_TIME="2013-05-21 10:05" CHECKOUT_TIME="2013-05-21 10:05" SHARE_CUSTOM="zeiser-rasumak.a:DBG5200"/>
>
<USER NAME="xu.d" HOST="DBG4970" IP="172.16.225.126" USED_LICENSES="25000" LOGIN_TIME="2013-05-21 10:25" CHECKOUT_TIME="2013-05-21 10:25" SHARE_CUSTOM="xu.d:DBG4970"/>
>
<USER NAME="zeiser-rasumak.a" HOST="DBG5200" IP="172.16.225.127" USED_LICENSES="21000" LOGIN_TIME="2013-05-21 11:27" CHECKOUT_TIME="2013-05-21 11:27" SHARE_CUSTOM="zeiser-rasumak.a:DBG5200"/>
>
<USER NAME="zeiser-rasumak.a" HOST="DBG5200" IP="172.16.225.127" USED_LICENSES="2000" LOGIN_TIME="2013-05-21 11:48" CHECKOUT_TIME="2013-05-21 11:48" SHARE_CUSTOM="zeiser-rasumak.a:DBG5200"/>
>
<USER NAME="zeiser-rasumak.a" HOST="DBG5200" IP="172.16.225.127" USED_LICENSES="21000" LOGIN_TIME="2013-05-21 11:49" CHECKOUT_TIME="2013-05-21 11:49" SHARE_CUSTOM="zeiser-rasumak.a:DBG5200"/>
</FEATURE>
<FEATURE NAME="HWAIFPBS" VERSION="12.0" VENDOR="ALTAIR" START="2013-03-26" END="2014-03-31" USED_LICENSES="0" TOTAL_LICENSES="2147483647" SHARE="CUSTOM ,VIRTUAL"/>
<FEATURE NAME="HWAWPF" VERSION="12.0" VENDOR="ALTAIR" START="2013-03-26" END="2014-03-31" USED_LICENSES="0" TOTAL_LICENSES="2147483647" SHARE="CUSTOM ,VIRTUAL"/>
```

I want to get the other attribute values...

Comment: What does you C# script odd to print? Also you gave invalid xml, there is no closing tags for `LICENSE_PATH` and `LM-X`

Comment: it is a snip the xml is larger ...xD

Comment: the xml has 1500 lines with FEATURE

Comment: So you thinks it's better to present incomplete, invalid, unformatted xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Parent` property. I've modified your xml to make it valid. Next code print all values from your foreach loop

```
string search_string = "GlobalZoneEU";

var xDoc = XDocument.Load(path_of_hw);

var users = xDoc.Root
                .Elements("LICENSE_PATH")
                .Select(license => license.Element("FEATURE"))
                .Where(feature => (string)feature.Attribute("NAME") == search_string)
                .Select(feature => feature.Element("USER"));

foreach (var xle in users)
{
    Console.WriteLine(xle.Attribute("NAME").Value);
    Console.WriteLine(xle.Parent.Attribute("VERSION").Value);
    Console.WriteLine(xle.Parent.Attribute("VENDOR").Value);
    Console.WriteLine(xle.Parent.Attribute("START").Value);
    Console.WriteLine(xle.Parent.Attribute("END").Value);
    Console.WriteLine(xle.Attribute("USED_LICENSES").Value);
    Console.WriteLine(xle.Parent.Attribute("TOTAL_LICENSES").Value);
}
```

prints:

```
SYSTEM
12.0
ALTAIR
2013-03-26
2014-03-31
2000
147000
```